# Need to check if a collection exists

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to check if a collection already exists in Meteor? Or a way to execute this Mongodb function [db.getCollectionNames()] inside meteor server code, so I can get back an array of all the collection names in Mongodb and iterate over these collection to find the one that I need?

Scenario:
I want to create a collection based on user input in a form. For example if I ask the user their birthdate. I want to create a collection named "1980". This collection will now store all the user who were born in 1980. So the first user with this year of birth will create this collection and future users with the same birth year will be added to this collection.

Thanks

Comment: What's the benefit of creating a new collection on user input instead of creating all of the collections ahead of time or just using one collection for all of the years?

Comment: This is just a scenario I presented to make the question more clear...I wanted to know if this kind of thing is possible and if 'Yes' then how?

Comment: You could store your collections in a JavaScript object, and then check that object for a collection with a certain name before creating a new one. I'm still not sure that there are any situations where you would want to dynamically create collections on user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can discover collections using this package: https://github.com/dburles/mongo-collection-instances

```
Mongo.Collection.getAll()
```

Returns an array of objects containing:

- name (The name of the collection)
- instance (The collection instance)
- options (Any options that were passed in on instantiation)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do this **only to check if the collection exists**:

```
var Audio = new Mongo.Collection("audio");


if (Meteor.isClient) {

    // return or do something 

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        // code to run on server at startup
        // Simple if statement to check collection
        if (Audio)
            Audio.insert({ item: 'card' , qty: 23 });
    });
}
```